# Is a possible continue to use web application when not connect internet?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

After load web application complete. Is a possible to continue to use web application when not connect internet ?

[image]

This is web application that user is machine.

Comment: As FCin pointed out, you can use local running Applications. You wont be able to use sites that require server side Components like for example AJAX.

Comment: Generally you could not do a single post or get to any of the pages of the website. The only it would work is all the client code, namely javascript, flash, silverlight, that does not interact with remote resources.

Comment: this only works with applications which were designed to work this way; eg. to store to LocalStorage and the upload changes on network re-connect... one can't just use any application alike that, for the reasons stated above.

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is possible, but only if the application is written to work like that.

Look up 'Progressive Web Apps'

https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/progressive-web-apps/

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/